# PHP - Extract a tags from a url

Tags: php

I'm working on a script which have to extract all a tags from a URL but not only the value from a tag, I mean all a tag code like this:

```
<a href="test">Text</a>
```

I find something with preg_match_all but this only extract the values from href, title, etc, not the entire a tag code.
What should I make?

Comment: you should also look into HTML parsers, [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) in particular

Comment: i found good function right now thanks you

https://github.com/aaronclinger/relative-url-helper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a html parser : 
[A HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ let you manipulate HTML in a very easy way!](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: i can't extract full path using this library

Comment: @dev.bashar with $element->href , you can get full path .

Comment: no i can't

it's return about_us.php
services.php
portfolio.php
i need the full path with http

Comment: some of returns links like ../../services

Comment: i found what i am looking for here
github.com/aaronclinger/relative-url-helper thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [Simplehtmldom](http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications) library to get data from url

```
// Include the library
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html('http://davidwalsh.name/');

// Find all "A" tags and print their HREFs
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) 
    echo $e->href . '<br>';

// Retrieve all images and print their SRCs
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->src . '<br>';
```

Comment: i can't extract full path using this library